# What does the pound sign represent in a language?

Tags: string, regular-language, automata

```
 L = { w#w#w | w ϵ {0,1}* }
```

What are some string outputs for this language? The pound sign is throwing me off. Is it the same as www? For example w = 01 so 010101 is in the language of L?

Answer (score 0):

So, the pound sign (or sometimes the `$` sign) is used in formal language theory as a separator. It's just some symbol that is not already in your original alphabet. So, formally what that means is that you are considering words on the extended alphabet containing three symbols `{0, 1, #}`.

The language you described is basically a word replicated three times seperated by `#`. Here are some examples of words in the language: `0#0#0`, `111000#111000#111000`, `###`. Here are some examples of words not in the language: `0`, `1###`, `01#11#11`.